# terraform init failed new project

Tags: terraform

i am new to the terraform doing setup in home computer to learn. i have created two file called terraform.tf and backend.tfvars here i defined terrafrom version and name of the s3 bucket to save state.

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 0.15.3"
  backend "s3" {}
}
```

```
bucket               = "terraform-application-infra"
key                  = "tf-state.json"
region               = "us-east-2"
workspace_key_prefix = "environment"
```

before running terraform init command i have created new namespace

```
terraform workspace new development
```

After this i am trying to execute the below command

```
terraform init -backend-config=backend.tfvars
```

But i am getting error like this

```
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\Terraform> terraform init -backend-config=backend.tfvars

Too many command line arguments. Did you mean to use -chdir?
```

could you please help me on this

Comment: Are you sure this is what you really did? `terraform workspace new development` should error out if you hadn't run `init` first.

Comment: you mean we need run terraform init command first then i need go with other command?

Comment: PowerShell on Windows is notorious for parsing the command line and then passing it to external commands in a slightly different way than you typed it. I think that's what's happening here: PowerShell is corrupting that `-backend-config` option in some way and so Terraform is unable to parse it. You could test that by running the command in the standard Windows Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) instead of in PowerShell.

Comment: I used git bash to use the terraform command now above error resolved